# why can't i get results from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been working on a new website and my script that i use for writing/deleting news/blog entries doesn't want to work anymore for some reason while it still works on another webpage i made.

I can upload news/blog content to my database, but when i want to let the script show the content of the database so i can select an entry to delete, it gives me this message: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/html/includes/conn.php on line 26

I am aware about Mysql being deprecated, but when i try to change my script to mysqli my whole script stops working, including the upload part which does work now...

when i change the script, it gives me errors on the following parts:

```
$result=mysqli_query($sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

mysqli_close();
```

giving me the following errors:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   /var/www/html/delete_multiple.php on line 16
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /var/www/html/delete_multiple.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /var/www/html/delete_multiple.php on line 36
>
> Warning: mysqli_close() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   /var/www/html/delete_multiple.php on line 64

and the upload results in: error updating database. which is basicly coming from this part of the script...

```
mysqli_query($query) or die ('error updating database');
```

i added my code and hope somebody can help me find where i am going wrong...

```html
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Get our database connector
require("includes/conn.php");
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){ // Check delete button is clicked
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){ // loop only checked items and delete
   $sql = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE id='$del_id'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
  }
}

?>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY ID";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Selecteer welke berichten verwijderd of veranderd moeten worden</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Datum</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Nieuwsbericht</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
                    echo "<p>";
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['date']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['blog']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php 
     echo "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 



mysqli_close();
?>

</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<a href="blogupload.php" title="Back">Back</a>
```

```html
<?php
 
// Call our connection file
require("includes/conn.php");
 
$date=$_POST['date'];
$blog=$_POST['blog'];

$query="Insert into blog (date, blog) values ('$date', '$blog')";  

mysqli_query($query) or die ('error updating database'); 


echo "Het nieuws is geupdate met '$date', '$blog'. De pagina zal over 5 seconden terug naar blogupload gaan.";
header('Refresh: 5; url=blogupload.php');
?>
```

Comment: **Please** read up about SQL injection...

Comment: RTM: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp mysqli_query needs a connection as first param!

Comment: i got the errors fixed, but for some reason it makes the needed rows equal to the entries in the database, but the results are still empty :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
```

The `mysqli_query()` function expects a connection as first parameter.
So this call shouold look more like:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Alternatively in case you like object oriented programming (`$mysqli` is the connection object):

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: thx! that did solve most errors but i still have this error:

Warning: mysqli_close() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/html/delete_multiple.php on line 64

and the results are still empty, although the rows are equal to the entries in the database now

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are using the same standard for database connectivity. I mean are you sure you are using mysqli_connect() function for your database connectivity?.

Other strong possibility is the accuracy of your query. coz usually when the query is wrong, or sorting the result by incorrect field, you will get the result as null and I believe thats why your query doesn't fetch the data from database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is my connection script...


should be good.

<?php

// Input your information for the database here
// Host name

$host = "localhost";

// Database username
$username = "user";
 
// Database password
$password = "password";

// Name of database
$database = "database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$database) or die ("Could not connect");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>

Comment: i did solve the errors but still no result except for the right amount of rows on the page...